# Powershell logging from Invoke-Expression with encoding

Tags: powershell, batch-file, logging, encoding

I have an specific scenario where I have to log a batch file using Invoke-Expression in Powershell but my logs are being saved with "UCS-2 Little Endian" Encoding and I would like to save it with UTF-8 or any other encoding.

This is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

batch file (test.bat):

```
echo Test
```

Powershell file (test.ps1):

```
Invoke-Expression "c:\test.bat > log.txt"
```

Is there a way I could change the encoding on log.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
C:\test.bat | Out-File C:\log.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

Or if for whatever reason you really have to use `Invoke-Expression`:

```
Invoke-Expression "C:\test.bat" | Out-File C:\log.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

Note that this will overwrite log.txt everytime. If you want to append to the file do this:

```
Invoke-Expression "C:\test.bat" | Out-File C:\log.txt -Encoding UTF8 -append
```

or

```
Invoke-Expression "C:\test.bat" | Add-Content C:\log.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Out-File did the trick thanks. BTW if you use Add-Content the log won't be accessible until the bat has finished. If you want to append using Out-File you can add the -Append option to it. Invoke-Expression "c:\test.bat" | Out-File c:\log.txt -Encoding UTF8 -Append

Comment: apparently i must have been blind when i wrote that because i´m pretty sure i checked if out-file had an -append parameter (because i was pretty sure it had one) and i didnt see it :o